# Forwarding UIPanGestureRecognizer to next responder

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

Basically, I have 2 `UIScrollView`.

The 1st one takes the whole screen and contains the 2nd one.

When I do a `Pan gesture` in the 2nd `UIScrollView`, I want it to be recognized as a `Pan gesture` ONLY if the horizontal velocity of the gesture is at least 4 times bigger than the vertical one.

If it's under, I want the gesture to be forwarded to the next responder (the 1st `UIScrollView`).

I tried overriding `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` on the 2nd `UIScrollView` and check the velocity there but if I return false, the pan gesture is not recognized (which is what I want) but it's not forwarded to the next responder either.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false;

Comment: No, it is still the same.